# Can I use C# for an embedded device with GUI?

Tags: c#, embedded

I am about to write a program by C# for an embedded device with GUI. Someone told me that I can install a Windows ARM and code a Winform/WPF program. I want the operating system to only run my program, just like Windows IoT.

However, Windows IoT died for many years.

In spite, .Net Core can run in an embedded device by Linux while it doesn't support running with GUI directly.

Now can I use C# for an embedded device with GUI? How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Core is designed to run on any type machine including embedded devices.  Most embedded devices use Linus so you have to download the runtime version of Core.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng However, Core doesn't support GUI in Linux.

Comment: Do a google search for "c# gui linux".  Here is one good result : https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/develop-cross-platform-net-core-desktop-apps-on-linux-with-xaml-bf3dbba9afa0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course you can use C# for embedded programming. Myself I use Winforms with the .NET Compact Framework 3.5 on a Windows CE 6.0 embedded computer. It is a bit outdated - but it works.

As far as current technology goes, have you looked into MAUI? It's a cross-platform GUI for .NET Core, so it should also run on linux:

[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/)

Or you could maybe use Qt with a .NET core wrapper like QmlNet.

It is possible!

Comment: MAUI seems nothing about embedded devices. Actually, I am looking forward to Microsoft update Windows IoT while it seems to be abandoned.